# How to find the dual cone?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, dual-cone

The similar question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660137/finding-the-dual-cone) , but I do not see the desired answer.

Assume a cone $K=\{(x,y) |\ x+y=0\}$, find the dual cone of $K$.

The definition of dual cone is here: $K^*=\{y|x^{T}y\geq0, \forall x\in K \}$

And the given answer is $K^∗=\{(x,y)| \ x-y=0 \}$

I am very confused. Where is the $\geq$ in the definition formula?? Why it disappears?  How could I derive the dual cone from the definition ?

Any help is appreciable . Thanks!

**Edit:** Another question: find the dual cone of $K=\{(x,y)∣|x|≤y\} $, in the question, we could use the inequality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the cone $K$ is a subspace, then the dual cone is the orthogonal complement of $K$.

This is because $x^T y \geq 0$ for all $x$ in $K$ implies that $x^T y = 0$ for all $x$ in $K$ (when $K$ is a subspace).

More detail: Assume that $K$ is a subspace let $y \in K^*$ (the dual cone for $K$).  If $x \in K$, then $-x \in K$ also (because $K$ is a subspace), and so it follows from the definition of $K^*$ that $y^Tx \geq 0$ and $y^T(-x) \geq 0$.  In other words, $y^T x = 0$.  Hence, if $x \in K^*$, then $x \in K^\perp$ (the orthogonal complement of $K$).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know what you mean. But when does the inequality come to effect? I have edited my question ( add another question) Thanks!

Comment: For the new question, if you visualize $K$, you will see that it looks a bit like an ice cream cone. And if you think it $y^Tx \geq 0$ as meaning that the angle between $x$ and $y$ is at most 90 degrees, then you can visualize what the dual cone must look like.